# Covert to unix timestamp

Tags: scala, datetime

I want to convert the date by passing year, month, day, hour, minute and seconds to unix timestamp in scala.

def toUnixTimeStamp(year: String, month: String,day: String,hour:String, minute:String,second: String) =
{
   ???
}
And year, month and day should be today's date

toUnixTimeStamp("2020","6","1","3","3","0") should return 1591023823

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.ZoneOffset

def toUnixTimeStamp(year: String, month: String, day: String, hour:String, minute:String,second: String): Long = { 
  return LocalDateTime.of(Integer.parseInt(year), Integer.parseInt(month), Integer.parseInt(day), Integer.parseInt(hour), Integer.parseInt(minute), Integer.parseInt(second)).toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC)                                                                                                         
}
```

Please note you may need to specify the correct timezone if it is not UTC.